# Increase checkbox size in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, checkbox, internet-explorer-11

I'm having a pathetic issue with **Internet Explorer 11** since it doesn't scale the checkbox properly unlike **Firefox** which does it right. Here's my css code :

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand');
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5); /* FF */
    transform: scale(1.5); 
    padding: 5px;
}
```

I replaced the `-ms-filter` with this, but it didn't work :

```
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand',
        M11=1.5320888862379554, M12=-1.2855752193730787,
        M21=1.2855752193730796, M22=1.5320888862379558);
```

and then with this, but it still didn't work:

```
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
```

Unfortunately, none of my attempts were successful and nowhere in SO does it say how to fix it. Normally `scale()` is supposed to work on IE 9 but it seems like they disabled it in IE 11. As I said, it works fine in Firefox but not in IE 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) I read:

> [5] Internet Explorer 11.0 supports the -webkit [prefixed variant as an alias for the default one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj127312#code-snippet-1).

If that doesn't help, this might be an issue that is specific to checkboxes. However, there is a better way to style checkboxes using **HTML** and **CSS**:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + .cb {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  margin: -4px 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: .2s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px white;
}
input[type=checkbox] + .cb:before {
  content: "✓";
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}

input[type=checkbox] + .cb:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #0055ff;
  border-color: #0055ff;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .cb {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px #0055ff;
  border-color: #0055ff;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .cb:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px #3377ff;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <div class="cb"></div>
  Style checkbox with CSS
</label>
```

Comment: That is ugly but it works, and in IE11 for my benighted customers.